# Unresponsive keyboard and trackpad on MacBook Pro 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

I have a MacBook Pro 2015 model (A1052). About two days ago, the keyboard and trackpad went completely unresponsive. On the trackpad, the force touch seems to be active but the cursor does not move. I am not able to reset the NVRAM or the SMC since the keyboard is unresponsive. After a bit of searching, I saw that many have recommended replacing the small cable that connects the trackpad and the keyboard. I got a new one and tried that as well but still no joy! Apart from taking it to the service center any other ideas?

Comment: It has failed.  The only thing you can really do is test to see if it’s the USB bus or just the top case assembly.  Plug in a USB keyboard. If it works, it’s the top case and it needs to be replaced

Comment: An external keyboard and mouse work just fine. When you say the top case, are you referring to that small cable just above the battery?